# ActiveRecord saves object when adding to association collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

From the Rails [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> Adding an object to a collection (has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many) automatically saves that object, except if the parent object (the owner of the collection) is not yet stored in the database.

**I would like to prevent this save from occurring (for better or worse)**. I've come up with three strategies and would be curious to hear which one is recommended.

1. Block access to the DB during "<<". I posed the question of how best to accomplish this in another question: [How can I prevent ActiveRecord from writing to the DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492099/how-can-i-prevent-activerecord-from-writing-to-the-db). The proposed solution seems quite feasible.
2. Leveraging the caveat of "except if the parent object is not yet stored in the db". Looking at the rails code, this condition is determined with the new_record? method. I wrote a little method that makes an object think it's new for the duration of a block.

   ```
   # model.rb
   def appear_as_new_record
     instance_eval { alias :old_new_record? :new_record? }
     instance_eval { alias :new_record? :present? }
     yield
     instance_eval { alias :new_record? :old_new_record? }
   end

   # used like this:
   model.appear_as_new_record do
      model.gadgets << gadget
   end
   ```
3. Using the 'build' method, to attach the object to the collection. This would like something like this (I know this doesn't cover all the edge cases)

   ```
   new_gadget = model.gadgets.build(gadget.attributes)
   new_gadget.id = gadget.id
   ```

   there are quites a few scary things about this approach... but namely, it won't do a copy by reference. So if gadget also had a collection of objects already loaded, they wouldn't be accessible via the model without having to hit the db.

Comment: I think you're in for a world of hurt here unless you implement your own method on the side instead of hacking the Activerecord method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in doing this?  Is it simply to iterate over the association collection?  I'd suggest the `build` approach but I'm not quite sure what you're after.  Can you show the `gadgets` association on the `model`?

Comment: The goal is to load the parent from the DB, and load the child from the DB, modify the child's attributes in memory, and add it to the parent. The problem I'm running into is that adding it to the parent causes the attributes I've changed in memory to be written back to the DB (which I don't want).